# Why does the following Riemann integral exist, but the other doesn't?

Tags: integration, riemann-sum

By definition if the upper integral equals the lower integral, then $ f $ is Riemann integrable.

An example of a Riemann integrable function is $ f(x)=0 $ if $ x\in(0,1] $ and $ f(x)=1 $ if $ x=0 $.

But then why is the function defined by $ f(x)=0 $ if $ x\in(0,1) $ and $ f(x)=1 $ if $ x=0,1 $ not Riemann integrable?

Comment: If you're looking at integrable on $[0,1]$ then both your functions are Riemann integrable.

Comment: Yes I am looking on that interval..but isn't the second example not?

Comment: maybe I am making a mistake computing the upper and lower integrals

Comment: @kay No, it is integrable. The lower sums are all zero. The upper sums are equal to the sum of the lengths of the intervals on the far left and far right, but these may be taken to be arbitrarily small.

Comment: Remember you're taking the $\sup$ and $\inf$ over the upper and lower integrals. Not just any particular one!

Comment: why can the upper sums be taken to be arbitrarily small?

Comment: @kay : It is the intervals that can be taken to be arbitrarily small.  Those in turn make the sums small.

Comment: @kay For concreteness, if the partition of $[0,1]$ is into equal sized intervals each of length $1/n$, the second of your integrals will have upper sum $1/n+1/n=2/n,$ which goes to zero as $n \to \infty.$

Comment: so it works for [0,1], but what if the interval was something like [2,4]? then how do you calculate the upper sum? (edited question)